# How to get current document id in Firebase Firestore in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have these two document IDs (I am going to have more in the future)

[image]

In some part of my code when the user taps on a Table View Cell, I am updating my Firebase using this code:

```
let dbCollection = K.FStore.db.collection(K.FStore.User.UsersCollectionName).document("EMSce9qnfNnPmn8JBobn")
if let textFieldText = textField.text {
    dbCollection.updateData([
        self.userDataInsideTableViewKeysArray[indexPath.row] as! String : textFieldText
    ]){ err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error updating document: \(err)")

        } else {
            print("Document successfully updated")
        }
    }
}
```

I have an app that when the user registers with the email and password authentication function provided by firebase, I create a db collection with that unique email alongside some other data (gender, age, phone number ...) The document ID is randomly generated, I can get access to all documentsID if I loop between them, however I want the document ID of this specific one so I can update it, I want to replace document("EMSce9qnfNnPmn8JBobn") with document(documentID) for that I have multiple users

Comment: 1) How do you (and how can Firebase) know what document needs to be updated? I.e. what in the document identifies the user is belongs to? 2) It is idiomatic to the the user profiles using the UID of the user as the document ID. I highly recommend you change your data to do that, in which case you can get the document for the current user with: `K.FStore.db.collection(K.FStore.User.UsersCollectionName).document(Auth.auth().currentUser.uid)`

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me. For the first question that exactly is why I am asking, I honestly have no idea. The Email Address is unique for every user. I don't know if that helps.
As for the second question, when I create the collection using K.FStore.db.collection(K.FStore.User.UsersCollectionName).addDocument(data:["Name" : name ...]), the documentID is randomly generated, how can I change it to the user's UID?

Comment: 2) See the first example in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document for how to specify the document ID yourself with (`setDocument`). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60418826 1) if you know something unique inside the document, you can use a query to find the document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

Comment: I wrote a more wordy version of this in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but if you want to get the document for the currently logged in user, that'd be:

```
K.FStore.db.collection(K.FStore.User.UsersCollectionName).document(Auth.auth().currentUser.uid)
```

Also see the documentation on [getting the currently signed-in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

---

**Update**

It seems that you have added your user profile documents with the `addDocument` calls, which means the IDs are unrelated to the user. In that case, you'll need to know something inside the document that uniquely identifies which document to update.

Since you say your email addresses are unique, and stored in the documents, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) to find the matching document(s), and then loop and update each of them:

```
db.collection("cities").whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                document.ref.updateData([
                    "fieldToUpdate": "newValue"
                ])
            }
        }
}
```

---

If you have a collection of user data, where each document belong to a specific user, and each user can only have a single document, it is idiomatic to use the UID as the document ID. To create a document with the UID as the document ID, see the first example in the documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

If you use this data structure, you won't need a query to find the profile document for a user, and can instead use the statement at the top to determine what document to update.

Comment: Hey man thank you for your answer, I actually tried that before but the ID I received is: "4J3kRyPR49euHhozyHHlR06Bfpe2" which is not equivalent to any of the above document ID, so When do document(uid) it says document not found!

Comment: So that means the document is not for the current user, which is why I started my answer off by saying "if you want to get the document for the currently logged in user". If that is not what you want, then please edit your question to clarify what determines the document you want to load.

Comment: Okay please read this comment and tell me if you understand now, I have an app that when the user registers with the email and password authentication function provided by firebase, I create a db collection with that unique email alongside some other data (gender, age, phone number ...) The document ID is randomly generated, I can get access to all documentsID if I loop between them, however I want the document ID of this specific one so I can update it, I want to replace document("EMSce9qnfNnPmn8JBobn") with document(documentID) for that I have multiple users

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. 1) Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show precisely that information. Hiding it in a comment down here, make it unlikely anyone else sees it. Plus, there's a decent chance I'll delete my answer as it no longer applies to your updated problem description. 2) I strongly recommend using the UID of the user as the document ID, as that's a pretty idiomatic way to both identify what document belongs to each user, and to ensure each user can have only one profile.

Comment: I used your second method of creating it with UID, works like a charm. And now my first try sounds so stupid to me lol. You learn new things everyday, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad we got you onto the better solution in the end. 